# Cast a hashtable.Keys into List<int> or other IEnumerable<int>

Tags: c#, hashtable, key

I know, I have other options, e.g. I could maintain a separate list of keys. Please don't suggest other options. I simply want to know if I can pull this off. Please don't ask me what problem I'm trying to solve, or anything like that. This is a pure and simple CS question.

I want to know if anyone knows of a way to take the keys from a `Hashtable` and cast them into a `List<int>` or some other type of `IEnumerable<int>` (given of course that my keys are in fact integers).

Given that I can do this with no problem:

```
foreach (int key in hashtable.Keys)
```

Why does this give me errors?

```
(List<int>)hashtable.Keys
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you have LINQ extension methods available you can do the following..

```
List<int> keys = hashtable.Keys.Cast<int>().ToList();
```

Also

```
List<int> keys = hashtable.Keys.OfType<int>().ToList();
```

might work depending on automatic boxing

Comment: +1. The specific reason being that `Keys` is an `ICollection`, which only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Also note that since the OP asks for "other `IEnumerable<int>`," you can forego the `ToList` and just type the variable as `IEnumerable<int>` (or `var`).

Comment: @Adam Robinson Good call, also thanks for adding your explanation, I am on a shoddy connection at the moment and editing my answer is slightly painful so I would have the OP defer to your comments for further information.

Comment: Thanks! I was misinterpreting the description of the `Cast<T>()` method. For some reason I thought that the type parameter was to be the type of the collection rather than the type of element. My fault for not reading! :)

Answer (score 4):

Because `foreach` requires `hashtable.Keys` to be an `IEnumerable<TKey>`, which it is. However, `hashtable.Keys` is NOT a `List<TKey>`; it is a simple ICollection, which is not the same. To convert it to a List, try some Linq:

```
List<int> keys = hashtable.Keys.OfType<int>().ToList();
```

This will basically enumerate through the Keys collection and add each element to a new List, then give you the List. OfType() is "safer" than Cast; Cast just tries to treat the whole collection as being an `IEnumerable<int>`, which can result in runtime errors or unpredictable behavior if any contained element is null or cannot be implicitly cast to an integer. OfType, by contrast, will iterate through the source and produce an enumerable of only the elements that actually are ints. Either works if you are SURE that all keys are integers.

Comment: `foreach` requires `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Technically yes, but if that enumerable is strongly-typed, you are required to define the item variable as being of that type (or something it can be implicitly cast to); you'll get a compiler error if you try to do something like `foreach(int id in MyCollectionOfReferenceTypes)`

Answer (score 0):

Because `hashtable.Keys` is a collection of objects which is not covariant with a list of integers.

Comment: If we're going to split hairs, covariance is not explicitly required; convertibility is.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `ICollection<int> keyCols = hashtable.Keys;`

Answer (score 0):

Either use Dictionary instead of non-generic version. Or use CastTo extension method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx for details on non-generic collection returned by Hastable.Key as well link to casting method you can use.

Answer (score -1):

Your `foreach` loop will throw an `InvalidCastException` if the `Keys` collection doesn't contain an `int`.

The cast to `List<int>` fails because the compiler can't convert a non-generic `ICollection` to a specific `ICollection<T>`

Comment: The cast fails because Keys is not a type that can be used as if it were a List; it's an ICollection, which is a very basic interface that doesn't expose the methods available on a List.